# face recognition raspberry pi

Tags: python, numpy, webcam

So I'm using the following code:

```
if box.is_button_up() or is_letter_input('c'):
    print 'Capturing image...'
    image = camera.read()
    # Convert image to grayscale.
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    # Get coordinates of single face in captured image.
    result = face.detect_single(image)
```

My problem is that I'm trying to use my usb webcam instead of the raspberry pi camera module. Any help on replacing that code?

Specifically the
    `image = camera.read()`

I've tried multiple variations of it such as `pygame.camera` and other variations. All I got was a numpy error and other errors.

Comment: It says that the .read function can only take 1 argument and that there were 2 given.

Comment: My bad; I meant `camera = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`.

Comment: I added that code right above the image = camera.read and got presented with a new error:

http://i.imgur.com/tkHuG99.png

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with CV2 replacing a webcam source on linux isn't always easy. How OpenCV works is it automatically draws from the systems default video source, which is known (usually) as video0. Unplug your usb webcam and go into a terminal and typing `ls /dev/video*`. Remember the number it says. Now plug in your USB webcam and type in the same thing and look for the new /video one, this is your USB webcam. This will effect your Pi until it is reset so it be careful. `mv /dev/videoX videoY` while X is the number of your USB webcam and Y the original number. This will replace your pi's default camera. This isn't permanent as you will need to do this every time your Pi starts up, an alternative to this is creating a bash file that runs on start up

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /dev/videoX videoY
```

and place that in the `/etc/init.d` directory of your pi. Don't forget you may need to use `chmod 755 /etc/init.d/FILENAME.sh` to give it permission to run

Comment: Something that may not be an issue to you, with my cv2.VideoCapture() the number inside the brackets is a 0, however this may just be my machine. I have just found that 1 will give me errors

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not importing numpy library, import numpy and then try.